# Getting data associated with that List item over setOnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have added few list items through adapter in this way.

```
classStudentsCollection.add(new mClassStudents(R.drawable.ic_profile, "DataOne", "DataTwo", "DataThree"));
```

And I have a listener that listen to the click event over any of those list items.

```
classStudentsView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(mainAppContext, "position" + position + "id "+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //get data associated with this particular list object
            }
        });
```

Now I want to retrieve all the data that has been associated with this `mClassStudents` list object. That is retrieve the values `"DataOne", "DataTwo", "DataThree"`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the object you clicked on, you can just call

```
parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

and cast the returned value to the specific object. If you created a custom adapter, in order to work correctly, your getItem has to return an item of the same you cast